# Music Production vs Audio engineering - Create my own music

Tags: audio, programming, career-advice

I don't know whether this is the right site to ask. If not I request you to please redirect me to the correct stack exchange site.

I have been playing keyboard for more than 15 years. I know the basics of piano and have the knowledge or grade 3 Piano. It was my dream to create instrumental music / jingles and export them in good quality and then sell it somewhere like spotify or youtube channel ( via monetization ). I have been creating music using FL Studio for a few years and the quality of sound was too low. So I have been planning to take a course on Audio Engineering or Music Production(Music Programming). But I am confused which one to take.

My requirement is to create music using a DAW, mix it and export it as a quality output.

**I have a DAW, Midi keyboard and average speakers with me. All I want is to output a song I create in a DAW in Good quality. Also I want to record the microphone input in good quality**

But on checking the course I came to know that mixing and mastering is a separate work and programming is a separate one. So If I choose Audio Engineering, I can make music myself. But I am not interested in Sound engineering ( Stage sound, TV channels etc ). I need to find an answer before it's too late. I am 28 now and finally I have the time and money to take a course.

Is Audio Engineering/ Audio technology really worth for me ? Or I should choose music technology ? I would like to create my own studio (basic), create music, help record via microphone some works of clients and export in quality. Here is the details of some courses

**Audio Technology**
[image: Audio Technology]

**Music Technology**
[[image: Music Technology2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I start mixing my first ever produced track?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44890/should-i-start-mixing-my-first-ever-produced-track)

Comment: check: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41105/is-music-school-worth-it/41110#41110 and https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44890/should-i-start-mixing-my-first-ever-produced-track/44891#44891

Comment: @frcake Not completely. Some points were helpful

Comment: Hi there, your question, and your associated comments, are really asking for opinion, and/or links to online training - these aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange. If you want to learn music production, you should find a music production course, but as per Mark's answer below an in-person course would give you much more than online.

Answer (score 1):

OK so a lot of these courses get terminology mixed up. "Audio Engineering" is really the discipline of designing audio hardware and software solutions for use in the audio industry. Audio Technology is again an entirely different thing.

You sound like you need a more music-focussed course, of which there are many to choose from, however my recommendation is to not spend money on these sorts of sausage-factory production courses. You can gain all the knowledge around DAW's you need from online sources - the main benefit of classroom style courses is being able to interact with other students.

Additionally, I would take lessons in music theory and keyboard skills/piano.

Comment: thanks for helping me out. I have an above average knowledge in Music theory. What I miss is those automation, mixing and mastering skills. Can I get those from online sources without proper equipments ? If so please suggest me some. I have a DAW, Midi keyboard and average speakers with me. All I want is to output a song I create in a DAW in Good quality. Also I want to record the microphone input in good quality.